# How can I know if an AnimationTimer is running?

Tags: animation, javafx, timer

Is there a way to know if an `AnimationTimer` is running or not? I would like to toggle a pause menu like this:

```
setOnKeyTyped(event -> {
  switch (event.getCode()) {
    case SPACE:
      if (animationTimer.isRunning()) { // What should I put here?
        animationTimer.stop();
      }
      else {
        animationTimer.start();
      }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: To me it seems a very bad design...

Comment: I listen to any suggestion.

Comment: Here it is a suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205977/javafx-why-animationtimer-has-not-getstatus-or-similar-method/41206746#41206746 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `start` and `stop` to keep information about whether the timer is running or not:

```
class StatusTimer extends AnimationTimer {

    private volatile boolean running;

    @Override
    public void start() {
         super.start();
         running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        running = false;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    ...

}
```

There seems to be no other way without accessing private members of `AnimationTimer`.

Comment: The [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) doesn't have a `getStatus()` method.